# Why does given constraint of n lift when I simplify?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> The numbers $a_n$ are such that
>
> $$
> {\frac {a_n} {a_{n-1}}} = {\frac {(n-1)(2n-1)} {(n+2)(2n-3)}} 
> $$
>
> Evaluate ${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n}$ when $a_1 = {\frac {\displaystyle 2} {\displaystyle 9}}$.

We can see that $n>1$ since $a_0$ is not defined.

After simplifying the given equation we get:

$$
a_n = {\frac {(n-1)(2n-1)}{(n+2)(2n-3)}} {\frac {(n-2)(2n-3)}{(n+1)(2n-5)}} \cdots {\frac {1 \times 3}{4 \times 1}} a_1 $$

$$
{a_n} = {6}{\frac {2n-1}{(n)(n+1)(n+2)}} \cdot a_1 
$$

Where the constraint $n>1$ is now lifted and it is now possible to use $n=1$
to confirm $a_1$ is indeed ${\frac 2 9}$.

Why is it so? The latter equation is equivalent to the given equaton,
so the constraint must remain the same and I should not be able use $n=1$to find $a_1$.

As to evaluating the solution, I can do it ( Solution = 1).
It is just a small side question that arose while I was solving it.

Many thanks in advance.

Chris

Comment: I think "the constraint $n > 1$ is now lifted" means the equation is also valid for $n = 1$, but it does not mean you can use it to find $a_1$. Observe that when you plug in $n = 1$, you get $a_1 = a_1$, which is valid.

Comment: Thank you Tunococ, leaving $a_1$ made sense. While I was solving it, I simplified everything including the value of $a_1$ and was suprised to find out n=1 still gives 2/9. The original equation excluding $a_1$ just equals to 1 when $n=1$. It is strange to see $n=1$ still valid though, I expected it to give out something similar to 1/0.

Comment: Yes it seems coincidental, but it is not completely unexpected. This kind of phenomenon sometimes leads to an interesting outcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you find prove something if and only if n>1.

edit :

$$
\forall n >1, {\frac {a_n} {a_{n-1}}} = {\frac {(n-1)(2n-1)} {(n+2)(2n-3)}} 
$$

It implie

$$
\forall n >1, {{a_n} } = {\frac {(n-1)(2n-1)} {(n+2)(2n-3)}}a_{n-1} 
$$

i.e.

$$
\forall n > 1, a_n = {\frac {(n-1)(2n-1)}{(n+2)(2n-3)}} {\frac {(n-2)(2n-3)}{(n+1)(2n-5)}} \cdots {\frac {1 \times 3}{4 \times 1}} a_1 $$

$$
\forall n > 1, {a_n} = {6}{\frac {2n-1}{(n)(n+1)(n+2)}} \cdot a_1 
$$

so you can't equal n to 1 and expecting it to work (here it work, but it's "luck")

Comment: The final formula is also valid when $n = 1$.

Comment: No, the formula is not valid, you can't remove the quantification.

Comment: Just because $n > 1$ implies $F(n)$ (where $F(n)$ is a predicate with variable $n$) does not mean $F(1)$ is not true.

Comment: $F(1)$ is $a_1 = a_1$, not $a_1 = 1$. $F(1)$ does not say anything about the actual value of $a_1$.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right, sorry. So here it's true... but you need to confirm it separatly (that's what all my post was about)

Comment: I see so it was just a good coincidence. Thanks for clearing it up guys.

Comment: It is not a coincidence ! They chose the value of $a_1$ such that the sum be $1$.